# drupal node_delete change default message success

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

In Drupal ,

Am using node_delete function for delete the node,

After deleted by default it showing the success message in green color text and white background [image]

How can I change the default delete message to read

> Delete Success

Comment: Question is in the image. I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set string overrides in your settings.php file for a site.

See here:

```
/**
 * String overrides:
 *
 * To override specific strings on your site with or without enabling locale
 * module, add an entry to this list. This functionality allows you to change
 * a small number of your site's default English language interface strings.
 *
 * Remove the leading hash signs to enable.
 */
# $conf['locale_custom_strings_en'] = array(
#   'forum'      => 'Discussion board',
#   '@count min' => '@count minutes',
# );
```

I think you would need

```
    $conf['locale_custom_strings_en'] = array(
   '@type %title has been deleted.'      => 'Delete Success',
 );
```

Comment: According I understand and learned, this is not a recomended way because you need hack Drupal... but if is the only way, noway, I need relearn.